# nginx rewrite based on part of URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm trying to set up nginx rewrites; I have it successfully set up to remove the extension:

`https://example.com/accounts?id=user-123` points to `https://example.com/accounts.php?id=user-123` using just try_files:

`location / { try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args; }`

I want to set up a second rewrite that goes before that; all the user IDs start with `user-`, so `example.com/user-sdgas3` should rewrite to `example.com/accounts?id=user-sdgas3`, `example.com/faq-abc8989as` should rewrite to `example.com/faqpage?id=faq-abc8989as`, `example.com/faq-abc8989as?view=true` goes to `example.com/faqpage?id=faq-abc8989as&view=true` etc.

What I tried was just adding variations of this to the very beginning for each URL extension:

`location ^/faq-(*)$ { try_files $faqpage?id=$1; }`

with no luck. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously don't need to setup a chain of rewrites (which seems like what you're trying). This would be wrong way to do things:

`/user-123 -> /accounts?id=user-123 -> /accounts.php?id=user-123`

... because obviously you can / should rewrite directly to the PHP handler file:

`/user-123 -> /accounts.php?id=user-123`

It does not seem like you have a single PHP entry-point router (the standard approach). If you *had* this, then `try_files` would be sufficient. But because you have many `.php` handler files, you would have to use `rewrite` for them.

Thus:

```
rewrite ^/user-(.*) /accounts.php?id=user-$1 last;
rewrite ^/faq-(.*) /faq.php?id=$1 last;

# This is only needed if /index.php can handle /this or /that route
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
} 

location \.php$ {
    ... the usual stuff for PHP-FPM
}
```